# Wait-Process generates ErrorRecord.TargetObject different than expected

Tags: powershell

I am getting a different `TargetObject` than expected when catching a `TimeoutException` from `Wait-Process` cmdlet.

When running the following code:

```
try {
    $a = Start-Process -FilePath notepad -ArgumentList ".\test.txt" -Passthru
    Wait-Process -Name $a.name -Timeout 1 -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
    #
    # Would expect $error[0].TargetObject to be equal to $a
    #
    Write-Output $($error[0].TargetObject.StartInfo.Arguments)
}
```

I would expect to get `".\test.txt"` as output but I get an empty string instead.
In fact, `$error[0].TargetObject` is object of type `System.Diagnostics.Process` but missing some attributes from the original `$a`, as for example, the attribute `StartInfo.Arguments`.

Does anyone know why `$error[0].TargetObject` is missing those attributes from the original `$a`?
Or is my assumption wrong?

Comment: Does this also occur if you specify the process by ID? `Wait-Process -ID $a.Id -TimeOut 1 -ErrorAction Stop`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, the issue persists even when calling `Wait-Process` by the process ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't just pass the *name* of your process object - pass the object *as a whole*:

```
try {
    $a = Start-Process -FilePath notepad -ArgumentList ".\test.txt" -Passthru
    # Note the use of -InputObject $a
    Wait-Process -InputObject $a -Timeout 1 -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
    $error[0].TargetObject.StartInfo.Arguments
}
```

If you pass only a `-Name` or `-ID` argument to `Wait-Process`, a *new* `System.Diagnostics.Process` is created behind the scenes (potentially even *multiple* ones with `-Name`), and that new instance lacks the original's `.StartInfo.Arguments` value.